# Annotating a plot of multiple files then creating a legend in a separate window the labels the filenames next to the annotations

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

Ok so I want to write a general plotting function that plots a list of files and annotates them chronologically (so the first file has a 1 above its plot etc). Each plotted file is labeled by its file name, but these names are too long to put into a subplot next to the data figure (file names are 35 characters). My motive for the annotations is that I often have more than 8 files, so I start repeating colors, and I might lose track because this data sometimes isn't plotted in an ordered fashion.

So far I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import fnmatch as fn
import os

# input a list of two columns
def plotter(columns, file_pattern, directory):

    #first i build the file list from the specified directory
    file_list = fn.filter(os.listdir(directory), file_pattern)

    for filename in file_list:
        x, y = loadtxt(filename, usecols=columns, unpack=True)
        plot(x, y, label=filename)

    show()
```

I can plot just fine, but now I want to create an integer annotation for each plotted file, then correspond that annotation to the label, with a legend that is displayed in a separate window entirely from the plot.

So far I've tried to just make the separate legend from a lot of different examples on this site, but I have not had any success, so I apologize if this seems like a duplicate, but I've searched and attempted already.

Comment: The annotations would be pretty cools, but aren't entirely necessary. If I could just make another window for the legend that I can interact with separately from the original plot, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you just want to open a new figure with the filenames, in the same order as the plots.

To achieve this you just need to add a list of the lines as well as the legends to a legend call in a separate axis, i.e.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import fnmatch as fn
import os

# input a list of two columns
def plotter(columns, file_pattern, directory):

    #first i build the file list from the specified directory
    file_list = fn.filter(os.listdir(directory), file_pattern)

    for filename in file_list:
        x, y = loadtxt(filename, usecols=columns, unpack=True)
        lines.append(plot(x, y)[0])
        legs.append(filename)


    figure()

    ax = axes()
    ax.legend(lines, legs)
    ax.set_axis_off()  

    show()
```